# DataSetVisualizer & Remote Debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, debuggervisualizer

We use Lab Manager to test on multiple platforms and do remote debugging by creating a Windows account with the same name and password on both the local dev box and the VM in Lab Manager (causes the VS debugger to think that the same account is being used on both boxes so it allows the debug server to be seen on the dev box). Then we run VS under the debug account and can debug remotely.

This all works great except that trying to run the DataSetVisualizer causes the following exception:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.RemoteObjectSourceException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\apps\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.DataSetVisualizer.dll' or one of its dependencies.

The dll is in the specified folder, and the folder allows Full control by Administrators (of which the debug account is a member). There are no other dlls in that folder.

I've also tried copying the visualizer dll to `Document and Settings\<debug_account>\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Visualizers` (the recommended path for custom visualizers). The exception is the same but references the MyDocs path instead of the VS install path.

Anyone else seen this? Any ideas?

Comment: +1 I've seen the same behavior in Visual Studio 2008 as well

Answer (score 4):

A colleague of mine found the answer: copy the visualizer dll to a location on the remote machine that mirrors the directory structure on your dev box.